# Input will not update onblur with ng-blur

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do something that should be pretty simple. When a user tabs out of an input field, I want to take their value and change the value to contain two decimal places for each number even .00

[I have a working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/xzXlDjOVkyZLPSswae5z?p=preview)

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" only-digits ng-blur="vm.cleanNumbers(vm.order.frameInformation.A)" ng-model="vm.order.frameInformation.A">
```

The controller is getting called and the value is changed but the input never reflects the change

```
function cleanNumbers(value) {
    if (value !== 0) {
        var hasDecimal = value.indexOf('.') > -1;
        value = value.replace('$', '');
        value = value.replace(/[,]+/g, '');
        value = parseFloat(value);

        if (isNaN(value)) {
            return 0;
        }

        value = value.toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

In the plunkr I'm logging the values and seeing what I would hope for the input to update with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your required answer.

The first issue is to use the controller as Syntax,

`ng-controller="test as vm"`

Since you are converting the value to Float and trying to display it in the text field,
 you are getting the same value since the text value of a float is same as the text.

**You have to convert the float back to string to display as you like.**

Here is the revised code,

```js
// Code goes here

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('admin', [])
        .controller('test', test);
        
        test.$inject = ['$log'];

    function test($log) {
      
      $log.debug('controller loaded');
        /*jshint validthis: true */
        let vm = this;
        vm.order = {};
        
        vm.cleanNumbers = cleanNumbers;
        
        function cleanNumbers(test) {
          $log.debug(test);
          let value = vm.order[test];
          if (value != 0 && value != undefined) {
                var hasDecimal = value.indexOf('.') > -1;
                value = value.replace('$', '');
                value = value.replace(/[,]+/g, '');
                value = parseFloat(value);

                if (isNaN(value)) {
                    return 0;
                }

                //value = value.toFixed(2);
                function toNumberString(num) { 
                   return value.toString() + ".00"
                }
                
                vm.order[test] = toNumberString(value);
                console.log(value);
                console.log(vm.order);
          }
        }
    }
        
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="admin">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="test as vm">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      {{vm.order}}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">A</label>
        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-blur="vm.cleanNumbers('A')" ng-model="vm.order.A" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">B</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-blur="vm.cleanNumbers('B')" ng-model="vm.order.B" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**PLEASE run above SNIPPET**

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/t9Vkfu26OLn299vVzD44?p=preview)

Comment: It will not always be a .00 at the end, I was just showing I wanted two decimal places which is why I did the .toFixed(2).

Comment: okay, but you cannot show a floated value in input type text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I encourage you to use the latest version of AngularJS (1.6.2 for now). There is still some bug fixes and good changes.

Secondly you are using "vm" controller prefix, but you are not saying that to your controller binder. In your `index.html`(plunkr) this line;

```
<body ng-controller="test">
```

Is I believe intended to be;

```
<body ng-controller="test as vm">
```

Also, even this is not handling the actual behaviour that you are trying to do, but I'm sure you can figure the rest of it out by yourself.

Comment: I'm using controller as syntax in my router on the actual project forgot to add it in the plunkr, thanks for the help